# Load balancing in apache kafka

Tags: load-balancing, apache-kafka

I am new to Apache Kafka and was playing around with it. If I have 2 brokers and one topic with 4 partitions and assume one of my broker is heavily loaded, will kafka takes care of balancing the incoming traffic from producers to the other free broker ? If so how it is done ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple partitions, it's the producers responsibility/choice of which partition they want to send it to.

> Producers publish data to the topics of their choice. The producer is responsible for choosing which message to assign to which partition within the topic. This can be done in a round-robin fashion simply to balance load or it can be done according to some semantic partition function (say based on some key in the message). [link](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_producers)
>
> In Kafka producer, a partition key can be specified to indicate the destination partition of the message. By default, a hashing-based partitioner is used to determine the partition id given the key, and people can use customized partitioners also. To reduce # of open sockets, in 0.8.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1017), when the partitioning key is not specified or null, a producer will pick a random partition and stick to it for some time (default is 10 mins) before switching to another one. [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Whyisdatanotevenlydistributedamongpartitionswhenapartitioningkeyisnotspecified?)

If you specify which partition you want the data to go into, it will always go into that specific partition. If you don't specify, the producer could send it to any partition. The Kafka broker never internally moves or balances messages/partitions.

I believe this decision is to provide certain [guarantees](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_guarantees) for the ordering of messages in a Kafka partition.

Answer (score 3):

Kafka producer tends to distribute messages equally among all partitions *unless you override this behavior*, then you need to have a look if the four partitions is distributed evenly among brokers.

It depends on what do you mean by *"one of the brokers is heavily loaded"*. if it is because of that topic or this cluster has any other topics (e.g. __consumer_offset).

You can choose the brokers in which partition resides with a cli tools with Kafka or with some kind of UI like yahoo [kafka-manager](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager).